# Spring boot tests with Testcontainers' kafka without DirtiesContext

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, testcontainers

My goal is to use kafka test containers with spring boot context in tests without `@DirtiesContext`. Problem is that without starting container separately for each test class I have no idea how to consume messages that were produced only by particular test class or method.
So I end up consuming messages that were not a part of even test class that is running.

One solution might be to purge topic of messages. I have no idea how to do this, I've tried to restart container but then next test was not able to connect to kafka.

Second solution that I had in mind is to have consumer that will be created at the beginning of test method and somehow record messages from latest while other staff in test will be called. I've been able to do so with embeded kafka, I have no idea how to do this using test containers.

Current configuration looks like this:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class KafkaContainerConfig {

  @Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
  public KafkaContainer kafkaContainer() {
    return new KafkaContainer("5.0.3");
  }

  @Bean
  public KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties, KafkaContainer kafkaContainer) {
    kafkaProperties.setBootstrapServers(List.of(kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers()));
    return new KafkaAdmin(kafkaProperties.buildAdminProperties());
  }

}
```

With annotation that will provide above configuration

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Import(KafkaContainerConfig.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:/application-test.properties")
@DirtiesContext
public @interface IncludeKafkaTestContainer {
}
```

And in test class itself with multiple such configuration it would looks like:

```
@IncludeKafkaTestContainer
@IncludePostgresTestContainer
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
class SomeTest {
...
}
```

Currently consumer in test method is created this way:

```
KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = createKafkaConsumer("topic_name");
ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> topicMsgs = Lists.newArrayList(consumerRecords.iterator());
```

And:

```
 public static KafkaConsumer<String, String> createKafkaConsumer(String topicName) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaContainer.getBootstrapServers());
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "testGroup_" + topicName);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class)

    KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
    kafkaConsumer.subscribe(List.of(topicName));
    return kafkaConsumer;
}
```

Comment: I understand your problem is you have different tests on different test classes sending messages to just one kafka topic. So, in each test case I would maintain the consumer listening and filtering messages until the expected one will be received. I would wrap the consumer using a `io.reactivex.subjects.Subject`. Then, I would use the test observer to assert the messages